# How Do I Put This Mattress Cover And Sheet Over This Bassinet Mattress?

Tags: infant, sleep

My wife and I are about to have our first baby - we've got a large crib in the nursery, and we purchased a bassinet to keep them by our bedside until they're bit enough to sleep on their own.

In preparation for the bassinet, I ordered a bassinet comforter and sheet - but looking at the mattress the bassinet comes with, I'm not sure how (if at all) this is supposed to go on the mattress.

The bassinet instructions do not help, and the cover and sheet did not come with any at all - should I just wrap it around the zip-up 'cover' that this comes with?  Or should I not use the cover at all?

Pictures included - for those who cannot view pictures, the bassinet I got is a Baby Joy Rocking Bassinet 2 in 1.

[image: BassinetAssembled]
[image: InsideMattressUnzipped]
[image: ThicknessOfMattress]
[image: MattressCoverAndSheet]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the most part, you shouldn't be using any "bedding" with a bassinet (or any infant).  See the [AAP's recommendations](https://pediatrics.aappublications.org/content/138/5/e20162938); in particular:

> Soft materials or objects, such as pillows, quilts, comforters, or sheepskins, even if covered by a sheet, should not be placed under a sleeping infant. If a mattress cover to protect against wetness is used, it should be tightly fitting and thin.

and later on:

> Soft objects,19,20,55–58 such as pillows and pillow-like toys, quilts, comforters, sheepskins, and loose bedding,4,7,59–64 such as blankets and nonfitted sheets, can obstruct an infant’s nose and mouth. An obstructed airway can pose a risk of suffocation, entrapment, or SIDS.

The sheet is also unnecessary, unless it's a waterproof cover.  If it's a waterproof cover, then it needs to be exactly sized and fitted; you may have trouble finding a perfect sheet for your bassinet, as there is no "standard" bassinet size.  If your bassinet manufacturer offers waterproof sheets, consider using those. Don't use a "pad" as that's code for a "soft" covering.

If the baby needs to be warmer than you're able to keep the room, swaddle the baby, or use a fitted garment.  (Note the comments on Swaddling lower on in the recommendations.)